# Unknown bug with xcode by NSKeyedUnarchiveObjectWithData,

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedunarchiver

An unknown bug with `NSKeyedUnarchiveWithObjectWithData` occurs.

I used `NSKeydArchiver` to archive a `[NSIndexPath:UIColor]` Dictionary to `NSData` in my project but a error occurred when I built the project in my XCode and iOS Simulator.

And then, when I try any of the iOS Simulator it can't build. I even changed the branch by git and build it, the same problem occurs.

But when I generate the IPA file and install it in my iPhone, it has no problem building the app.

This is the error and the source code. Does someone have a experience with this?

> "unarchiveObjectWithData:" Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

```
    let data = self.ud.objectForKey("data") as? NSData
    if let _ = colorData {
        colorDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data!) as! [NSIndexPath:UIColor]
    }
    if !colorDictionary.isEmpty {
        for (indexPath, color) in colorDictionary {
            self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
```

There's a NSUserDefaults and I'm saving the [NSIndexPath:UIColor] Dictionary to NSUserDefaults in order to use the data in continuously.

Comment: To Store any data into NSUserDefault , each value must conform **NSCoding** Protocol type then you can store it otherwise it gives Error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have no idea why even though i change the branch by git and a same problem occurs even though i'm not using the code above.